# How to add method to model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a model that looks like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Post extends Eloquent {
}
```

I then tried to add a method like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Post extends Eloquent {
    public static function create($type, $postid, $url, $author, $content)
    {
        $post = new Post;
        $post->type = $type;
        $post->postid = $postid;
        $post->url = $url;
        $post->author = $author;
        $post->content = $content;
        try
        {
        $post->save();
        echo $post;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            throw new Exception( 'Already saved', 0, $e);
        } 
    }
}
```

And in a controller, I tried to reference that method like this:

```
public function savepostController($type, $postid, $url, $author, $content)
{
    Post::create($type, $postid, $url, $author, $content);
}
```

When I run the controller I get `Controller method not found.`

Comment: Can you please provide more of the stack trace? It seems like this error is not coming from your model at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ,Here's an example

```
class Exports extends Eloquent {

    public static function my_exports($user)
    {
         // DB call here
    }
}
```

**Then in your route you could do**

```
Route::post('export/(:number)', function($user)
{

    $user_exports = Export::my_exports($user);

    // Do stuff here
});
```